# Repository which allows anonymous authorship

Tags: publications, data, online-publication

This question concerns a problem related to a paper submission in the field of psychological methods. As part of the review process, I was asked by the journal's editor to provide my appendices as online documents at an author-controlled site, and not in the main text (simply to shorten the paper). Since these documents will be reviewed as part of the journal's blinded peer-review process, the authorship of these documents should be blinded as well until the publication of the paper.

My question is which research-related sites allow this kind of submission (i.e., a document which is made available by an URL, with anonymous authors)? As far as I know, sites like arXiv or Zenodo do not allow anonymous submissions.

I am thankful in advance for any advise on this issue.

Edit: I am aware that a similar question addressed the anonymous storage of research data for a paper submission. However, the responses listed there (Dropbox, supplementary material in the submission) are not useful in my case. Dropbox is only a last resort, and I am not allowed to submit these documents as supplements.

Comment: Can't the journal editors recommend you a service? Surely this isn't the first time they encounter this situation, and they can't make a demand that is impossible to fulfill...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi but if they can, then this community can either?

Comment: Why does it need to be a research related site? Isn't the point just to make the files available to the reviewers at this point? Once it's accepted, you could use a non-anonymous site.

Comment: @JessicaB: It does not have to be a research-related site, but it would be preferable. I just want to make a professional impression.

Comment: This may not be the most helpful remark for you, but: why can't you just, um, append your appendices to the end of your document while it gets reviewed, and then if/when it gets accepted you can do with them what the editors want?  It will then be obvious how long the article will be both with and without this material.  What they suggest seems much more complicated all around, with no benefit to anyone.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Thank you for your suggestion, but this was exactly what I did in my first submission, and which I was asked to change. I think the overall length of the submission became too long.

Comment: Suggesting an author-controlled site for this purpose seems bad practice, to me. What prevents you from slapping Google Analytics on it and finding out who your referees are (or, at least, where they are) from the logs? (I am blaming the editor for suggesting it, though, not you.)

Comment: @Llarian: Right; in case it was not clear, I am criticizing the journal for sticking to a page-length policy without any good reason.  What could you do about it?  Well, one thing to consider is resubmitting to a different journal.  If this journal is the unique most appropriate one for your submission -- okay, probably don't do this.  Otherwise -- why not?  Editorial addle-patedness should not be rewarded.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your suggestions. After researching possible options online, I found a web service similar to Dropbox which is available to researchers at my (Swiss) university (https://www.switch.ch/de/drive/). I think this will do, since it allows the anonymous sharing of files via links. Probably similar services are available to researchers in other countries as well.

As a last resort, Dropbox could also be used for this purpose.

Comment: The referees will know that the author is Swiss, if you use them. Isn't it an issue for the double-blind review process?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I am not sure, but I will ask about it. Technically, the use of this service only shows that the person who uploaded these documents works in Switzerland, and does not reveal the authorship of the documents. I will consider the attachments for the Latex documents as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not a repository, but if you use Latex, you can [attach arbitrary files](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile) to a pdf document.